# As a(n) noun vs as only

Tags: grammar, writing

I wonder about the use of `as a` and `as (only)`  in writing. Can you explain when it is correct to quantify the noun when presenting oneself? I will paste some examples for clarity.

Are there any rules to follow?

**Example 1**

> a) As teacher, I meet many children.
>
> b) As a teacher, I meet many children.

**Example 2**

> a) Working as pilot, I fly airplanes.
>
> b) Working as a pilot, I fly airplanes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Germanic languages, like your (presumably) native German and Swedish, you avoid indefinite article for professions. However in English they are present. So in your case, "as a teacher, ... " should be the right form. Here's a [ngram plot](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20a%20teacher%2C%20as%20teacher&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20a%20teacher%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20teacher%3B%2Cc0) to support the idea.

Here's [an interesting article on definite and indefinite article use in English](http://www.davidappleyard.com/english/articles.htm), compared to some other languages, among which German. Note the following quote:

> Although greatly simplified, English article usage still poses a number of challenges to speakers of other European languages. Let's compare the German sentence *"Da er Botaniker ist, liebt er die Natur"* with the corresponding English one *"Being a botanist, he is fond of nature"*. You'll see that English puts an indefinite article in front of a profession but German doesn't. Conversely, English manages without articles in front of abstract nouns like nature, where German needs a definite article.

Comment: The ngram plot is very good. Speaking German and Swedish, I can confirm the challenge. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can see, OP's example **2a** could never be valid. **1a** requires a very specific (slightly contrived) context to be "valid/natural", which might be easier to see if we consider...

> 1: *[As breadwinner](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22As%20breadwinner%2C%20I%20don%27t%20make%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), I don't make quite enough money to support myself (or my family) in this job.*
>
> 2: *Dad had some hang-ups about his working wife taking away from his role [as breadwinner](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22away%20from%20his%20role%20as%20breadwinner%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl).*

In both the above contexts (which I consider to be perfectly well-formed sentences) it would be quite acceptable (but not *required*) to include the *definite* article ("the"). That's because of the pragmatically strong implication that there's only *one* breadwinner in the current context.

> 3: *Besides myself, the only other people employed by our tiny village school are the groundsman, the cook, and the part-time secretary. So **as [the] teacher**, I get to meet the parents of every pupil.*

In (3) above, using the *indefinite* article ("a") would be extremely unlikely, if not actually "invalid". But as a general principle, if using the *definite* article would be credible, it's also possible to omit it.

---

Assuming OP isn't a native speaker, the "correct" answer for the most common context is *Include the indefinite article*. But if that's all that's being asked about, perhaps the question should have been asked on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is another form - the pronoun form - of a profession, that personalizes it. It's something of a synecdoche, in that it represents a person by their trade. This may be the reason for the high occurrence of the original poster's form on the ngram. Consider:

"As teacher once told me, 'never split your infinitives.'" In this form, the profession "teacher" is actually standing in for another pronoun form representing a *specific individual* (and not a group in a common trade), such as the teacher's actual name. "As Mrs. Abigail, my third grade teacher, once told me…," etc.

If you filter this usage out of the ngram, I think you'll find that the occurrence of the original poster's form in common English drops to nearly nil.